# Solution check to Absolute convergence test

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

By the absolute convergence test, the series 
$$\sum \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} =\sum a_{n}$$
diverges since
$$\sum \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} < \sum \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$ and by the p-series 
$$\sum \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
diverges for $$p<1$$
and by the direct comparison test, since 
$$b_{n}= \sum \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$ diverges,
so does 
$$\sum \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$
But by the alternating series test,
$$\sum \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} =\sum a_{n}$$
converges and so the series
$$\sum \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} =\sum a_{n}$$
is conditionally convergent.

Does this look right?

Comment: In the second line you should not have $(-1)^n$ and you can compare with $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}> \frac{1}{n} $.

Comment: The negative was a result of type. I'm more curious with your choice of selection. Could you explain?

Comment: You should be able to see that $ \sqrt{n} \leq n,\, \forall n\geq 1 $

Comment: I see it and 1/(n^(p)) is the harmonic series for p=1 and it diverges. However, there doesn't seem to be a unique choice of selection.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to show that the series is not absolutely convergent in the first part.  One minor problem is that you need to write $\sum\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}$ since you're taking the absolute value and because the comparison test only works for series of non-negative terms.

More serious that is that you need to show that the terms of a series are greater than the terms of a divergent series in order to conclude that the original series is divergent.  Your inequality is going the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you. I'm on my way to rectifying the errors.